# Firebase Security rule to restrict up to some characters of a string

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

How to restrict user to save string that is above some limit?

I am getting **Invalid property access: target is not an object** if try to validate in security rules with **length** property of a string.

Answer (score 9):

The Firebase Security Rules now support a `length` property for strings, as well as several other string methods including `replace()`, `contains()`, `toUpperCase()`, `toLowerCase()`, etc.

See https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/#string_properties for more information.

Comment: The link is broken.

Comment: @IvanRubinson Fixed!

Answer (score 3):

[The syntax you can use in rules are detailed here.](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/rule-expressions/index.html)

<del>Unfortunately, being able to perform string operations (match, length, etc) are not available at this time.</del> **SEE ROB'S ANSWER BELOW, THIS FEATURE IS NOW AVAILABLE**

I know this is at least on the Firebase radar because I requested a similar feature some time ago.

If you explain the exact details of what you want to solve, it will allow for a much more specific answer; for now I'll give you some general ideas.

**Use a privileged app**

Monitor Firebase with a privileged application and whenever a value is written to the specific fields you need string validation on, check it manually and delete it if invalid.

Naturally, client validation will take care of all valid use cases. So this is only needed to prevent malicious insertions.

Alternately, you can approach this more as an audit. Just email any invalid strings to some address to be reviewed. Since the client is going to make sure the string is valid before insertion, you are once again just looking at bugs or malicious behaviors.

**Delegate writing to an API**

Instead of letting the client write privileged data, send it to an API and have the API write that data--making it read only to the client.

**Don't worry about it**

Do you really need to validate the length? Is it sufficient to simply look and see if it's a string? Is it really a concern that someone would "hack" the contents of a string? Probably not. It could be, but probably not.

And if it is a concern, can it be solved by another avenue? If there is a server involved, just use the process outlined above.

Comment: Thanks, I just wanted to limit up to some characters of a string. I am directly saving data to firebase from client side. I just needed string operation "length" in the security rule.

Comment: Yep, there isn't a length in the security rules yet : )